# Can I say "Any tiger is a dangerous animal"?

Tags: meaning, determiners, generic-noun-phrases

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> "Any tiger is a dangerous animal."?

A. A tiger in general is a dangerous animal.
B. Any tiger, even a sick one, is dangerous.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can, but in the context of your second sentence it makes more sense.

> *Two zoo workers are talking:*
>
> A. That old tiger can't be dangerous, it's hardly got any teeth left.
>   B.  Look, **any tiger is a dangerous animal**.  Always treat them with respect.

In a similar way, you can say

> While most are not serious, emergency room workers treat **any** complaint of chest pain as if **it might be** a heart attack.
>
> This baseball team is a mess.  I think, at this point in our terrible season, **any win is a major victory**.

Answer (score 4):

It could mean either one of your options, and perhaps it could be nuanced a couple other ways as well.

By the way, it's hard to take such a short English sentence and simply ask, "What does this mean?" Native speakers will invariably ask for more context.

I remember an exercise one time where a professor asked us to consider what went through our minds when we heard this sentence:

> Mary had a little lamb.

For those who aren't' aware, *Mary Had a Little Lamb* is an old [nursery rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Had_a_Little_Lamb) and [simple song](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/SaxophoneMaryHadALittleLamb.gif) that most people (at least in the US) are first exposed to at a rather early age. So, when we first hear that sentence, most people imagine something like this:

[image]

But the class was asked:

- What if you knew that Mary was my girlfriend, and I had just told you that we went out to dinner last night?
- Or what if Mary was the name of my sheep, and you knew she had been pregnant?

Suddenly, the pictures change quite a bit:
[image] [image]

---

In summary, the title of your question asks: ***Can I say, “Any tiger is a dangerous animal”?***

My answer to that is: Absolutely. You can say anything you want. But that one is even grammatical.

You go on to ask: ***What does it mean?***

My answer to that is: It means I'll be careful to avoid tigers – especially at night.

Comment: Re: "By the way, it's hard to take such a short English sentence and simply ask, 'What does this mean?' Native speakers will invariably ask for more context": Sadly, that's not true. Native speakers will often just assume a certain context (without even realizing that they're making an assumption).

Comment: @ruakh - Perhaps so, but I was mostly talking about here on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

It can and does mean both. But it's a poorly constructed sentence.

To emphasize sentence A:

> A tiger is always dangerous.

Here the emphasis is on the verb to be, it implies that whatever state a tiger is in, it is dangerous.

To emphasize sentence B:

> Tigers are dangerous animals.

Here the emphasis is on what sort of animal tigers are, i.e., dangerous.

Comment: I like what you're saying here. But there are a few contexts where the OP's sentence might be quite appropriate (like the sample zookeeper dialogue in @Andrew's answer).